# Iron Router, Meteor app crashes when router.js is placed in /lib

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

WINDOWS 7 64BIT

METEOR V 1.2.1

IRON:ROUTER V 1.0.11

I just started learning Meteor and I'm stuck trying to get iron router working properly, currently I have my router.js file in the client folder, which is working fine, but if I place it in the /lib folder the app crashes.

```
ReferenceError: router is not defined
at lib/router.js:1:1
```

Comment: What is in your router.js file?

Comment: Nothing, but in the tutorial I'm doing, it appears you don't need anything for the app to load properly.

Comment: i don't believe that there is nothing in the file =)) there **must be** something there

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you have successfully added the `iron-router` package: from the error thrown by the console, it's possible that you mistyped `Router` as `router`.

An excerpt from iron-router [repository](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router):

```
// Create some routes in a client/server JavaScript file
Router.route('/', function () {
    this.render('MyTemplate');
});
```

Comment: I'm using  Router.configure, but even when the file is totally empty, I can put the router.js file in the client folder, and it works fine, but even a completely empty router.js file in the lib, and the app crashes..

Comment: Wait, even an empty router.js file triggered an error? Now that's unheard of. Have you tried deleting that file (possibly a corrupt one) and creating a new one? Or have you tried putting `Router.route` or `Router.configure` in other client's javascript files?

Answer (score 0):

The fix that worked for me was to remove Iron Router, and the router.js file. Reinstall it, then create a new router.js file. Very possible that as Leonardy Kristianto suggested, the file was somehow corrupt. I've seen this problem several times on here, with no definitive answer, but it seems the overall consensus is to reinstall.

Make sure you have:

1. The current version of Meteor
2. The current version of Iron Router
3. A newly created router.js file